# External link in views slideshow

Tags: media, views

I have a views slideshow where an image is linking to the node. Now I want one of the slides to link to an external site.
How do I get this to work?
Maybe I can rewrite the output for the image field in a tpl.php file, but I don't know how to do it.
Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Drupal 7, all you need is using [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link) and [Linked field](http://drupal.org/project/linked_field) modules